# Handling a leading zero in a wsdl

Tags: xsd, wsdl, cxf

I got provided an XSD that had a type representation as follows:

```
<xs:element name="PhoneNumber">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
            <xs:pattern value="04[0-9]{8}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Now when we use Apache CXF to convert this from the XSD to autogenerated code which assigns it as a BigInteger.

So what I would like to know:

1. Is that piece of XSD valid? (I tend to think not as an Integer will never exist with a leading zero)
2. Is there anyway to get Apache CXF to handle such a condition and force the type to be a string?

Comment: I am not familiar with  Apache CXF but I am familiar with XSD so I can answer your first question: yes, that piece of XSD is valid. Is useful to diferentiate between "lexical space" and "value space"; for example, when we use `<xs:pattern value="1000"/>` we are restricting the lexical space and the only lexical form allwed will be "1000", however if we use `<xs:enumeration value="1000"/>` we are restricting the value space, and multiple lexical forms represent the same value in the value space, so with that enumeration the allowed values are 1000, 01000, +1000, 1e3, +001000, etc

Comment: More info in the [XSD specs on nonNegativeInteger](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#nonNegativeInteger). Note: I put this in a different content because stackoverflow said my first comment was to long

Comment: So what type would this translate to in Java?

Comment: I don't know, I am not familiar with wsdl, I only know that that piece of XSD is valid. Maybe you want to use xs:string if you want to (for example) store that value with the leading zero in a database.